# How do I prevent character escaping in PHP XSLT?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, escaping

I have a large, complex XML document that needs to be transformed twice with XSLT to achieve the desired result. Thanks to [michael's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702097/3880964), I got it to work perfectly when running the transformation locally (with xsltproc on the Terminal), but I can't get it to work the same way now that I've moved it to PHP.

The important part of the source document looks like this:

```
<BiographicalNote>
 &lt;p&gt;This text includes escaped HTML entities.&lt;/p&gt;
</BiographicalNote>
```

And the desired output:

```
<ParagraphStyleRange>
 <CharacterStyleRange>
  <Content>
   This text includes escaped HTML entities.
  </Content>
 </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
```

I need to do this transformation in two steps because I need to unescape the HTML entities and then process them as XML to apply further transformations. So the first step takes care of the bulk of the transformation, setting up the end document, but when it comes to sections with HTML is only does this:

```
<xsl:template match="BiographicalNote">
    <AuthorBio>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </AuthorBio>
</xsl:template>
```

Then I have a second XSLT to get rid of the `<p>` tags and do various other transformations with the `<em>`, `<b>` and `<span>` tags:

```
<xsl:template match="AuthorBio">
 <ParagraphStyleRange>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()"/>
  <Br/>
 </ParagraphStyleRange>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()|text()"> <!-- Not all HTML paragraphs have actual <p> tags. -->
 <CharacterStyleRange>
  <Content><xsl:value-of select="."/></Content>
</CharacterStyleRange>  
</xsl:template>
```

As I mentioned above, this works perfectly when I transform it locally with xsltproc. But with PHP, what I'm getting is this:

```
<ParagraphStyleRange>
 <CharacterStyleRange>
  <Content>
   &lt;p&gt;This text includes escaped HTML entities.&lt;/p&gt;
  </Content>
 </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
```

I've tried a few variations on the PHP code, but this is what's gotten my closest:

```
function processONIX () {
    // Load ONIX file
    $onix = new DOMDocument;
    $onix->load( 'HarbourONIX20141217.xml' );

    // Load ONIXtoICML XSL file
    $icml = new DOMDocument;
    $icml->load( 'ONIXtoICML.xsl' );

    // Configure the transformer
    $icmlproc = new XSLTProcessor;
    $icmlproc->importStyleSheet($icml);

    // Apply ONIXtoICML
    return $icmlproc->transformToDoc($onix);
}

function makeICML () {
    $temp = processONIX();

    // Load Inlines XSL file
    $inline = new DOMDocument;
    $inline->load( 'Inlines.xsl' );

    // Configure the transformer
    $inlineproc = new XSLTProcessor;
    $inlineproc->importStyleSheet($inline);

    // Apply Inlines
    $inlineproc->transformToURI($temp, 'ONIX.icml');
}

makeICML();
```

- This gives the result as shown above, with all the HTML bits escaped.
- Using transformToXML in processONIX() gives me nothing.
- Using transformToURI in processONIX successfully saves the file, and the HTML tags are correctly escaped: `<AuthorBio><p>This text includes escaped HTML entities.</p></AuthorBio>` But when I try to load it as a new DOMDocument in makeICML() (same way as in processONIX() ) it seems to load as an empty document. No idea what's happening here.

The issue seems to be in the makeICML() function, but that seems strange since it's almost exactly the same as processONIX(), only with different variable and file names. I can't figure out at which point the characters are being escaped, so: how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

The disable-output-escaping attribute is a directive to the serializer, and it has no effect unless you are serializing the output of the transformation, that is, turning it into lexical XML. In your first transformation you are using transformToDoc(), which creates the output as an in-memory tree, bypassing the serialization step. So disable-output-escaping has no effect.

Comment: In that case, what is the alternative? As I mentioned in the question, I also tried saving the first output to a document using transformToURI, then loading it into the second step as a new DOMDocument. The intermediate file seems to be fine, with all the characters correctly unescaped, but it loads as an empty document.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. A two phase transformation in which the intermediate result is serialized as lexical XML should work OK.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some error in the parts of the code that you haven't shared with your question, as when given that source XML:

```
$source = <<<XML
<source>
<BiographicalNote>
 &lt;p&gt;This text includes escaped HTML entities.&lt;/p&gt;
</BiographicalNote>
</source>
XML;
```

and given that first stylesheet:

```
$xsltA = <<<XSLT
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="BiographicalNote">
        <AuthorBio>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </AuthorBio>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
XSLT;
```

and given that second stylesheet:

```
$xsltB = <<<XSLT
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="AuthorBio">
         <ParagraphStyleRange>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()"/>
              <Br/>
         </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()|text()"> <!-- Not all HTML paragraphs have actual <p> tags. -->
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Content><xsl:value-of select="."/></Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
XSLT;
```

Performing the application:

```
echo $source2 = Proc::create($xsltA)->transform($source), "\n----\n";
echo $source3 = Proc::create($xsltB)->transform($source2), "\n";
```

Results in the following beautified output:

```
<AuthorBio><p>This text includes escaped HTML entities.</p></AuthorBio>
----
<ParagraphStyleRange>
  <CharacterStyleRange>
    <Content>This text includes escaped HTML entities.</Content>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
  <Br/>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
```

---

Full example code:

```
<?php
/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751339/how-do-i-prevent-character-escaping-in-php-xslt
 */

/**
 * Class Proc
 *
 * XSLT Processor
 */
class Proc
{
    private $proc;

    /**
     * @param string $xslt
     *
     * @return Proc
     */
    public static function create($xslt)
    {
        return new self($xslt);
    }

    public function __construct($xslt)
    {
        $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
        $proc->importStylesheet(
            $this->docFromString($xslt)
        );

        $this->proc = $proc;
    }

    public function transform($source)
    {
        $result = $this->proc->transformToDoc(
            $this->docFromString($source)
        );

        $result->formatOutput       = true;
        $result->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        return $result->saveXML($result->documentElement);
    }

    private function docFromString($string)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($string);
        return $doc;
    }
}

$source = <<<XML
<source>
<BiographicalNote>
 &lt;p&gt;This text includes escaped HTML entities.&lt;/p&gt;
</BiographicalNote>
</source>
XML;

$xsltA = <<<XSLT
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="BiographicalNote">
        <AuthorBio>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </AuthorBio>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
XSLT;

$xsltB = <<<XSLT
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="AuthorBio">
         <ParagraphStyleRange>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()"/>
              <Br/>
         </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()|text()"> <!-- Not all HTML paragraphs have actual <p> tags. -->
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Content><xsl:value-of select="."/></Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
XSLT;

echo $source2 = Proc::create($xsltA)->transform($source), "\n----\n";
echo $source3 = Proc::create($xsltB)->transform($source2), "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for this sample. As I mentioned above, the transformation works fine with xsltproc, so I really don't think there is a mistake with the rest of the code. As a test, I tried a variant of your code by loading the XML and XSLTs (same shortened version that you used) as new DOMDocuments (and removing the docFromString bit) and it only worked halfway. It gave me the correct result of the first transformation but nothing for the second. Any ideas?